# How to convert a stringfied JSON from a no-indentation and escape backslashes to a beautifully indented and free of escape characters JSON?

Tags: json, string, escaping, common-lisp, pretty-print

I am using Common Lisp, SBCL, and a famous library called [Dexador](https://github.com/fukamachi/dexador). The following s-exp:

```lisp
CL-USER> (dex:post "https://html2json.com/api/v1"
          :content (dex:get "https://ambrevar.xyz"))
```

Returns:

```lisp
"{\"error\":false,\"code\":null,\"message\":null,\"data\":{\"head\":{\"title\":\"\\u200e\",\"meta\":[{\"charset\":\"utf-8\"},{\"name\":\"viewport\",\"content\":\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\"},{\"name\":\"generator\",\"content\":\"Org mode\"},{\"name\":\"author\",\"content\":\"root\"}],\"link\":[{\"rel\":\"stylesheet\",\"type\":\"text\\/css\",\"href\":\"..\\/dark.css\"},{\"rel\":\"icon\",\"type\":\"image\\/x-icon\",\"href\":\"..\\/logo.png\"}],\"script\":[]},\"headers\":[{\"tagName\":\"h2\",\"textContent\":\"Contact\",\"attributes\":{\"id\":\"org4051da4\"}}],\"jsonLd\":[],\"iframes\":[],\"embeds\":[],\"imgs\":[],\"links\":[{\"text\":\"mail@ambrevar.xyz\",\"href\":\"mailto:mail@ambrevar.xyz\",\"attr\":{\"href\":\"mailto:mail@ambrevar.xyz\"}},{\"text\":\"0x9BDCF497A4BBCC7F\",\"href\":\"ambrevar.asc\",\"attr\":{\"href\":\"ambrevar.asc\"}}],\"forms\":[],\"tables\":[],\"content\":\"Contact\\nEmail: mail@ambrevar.xyz\\nPGP: 0x9BDCF497A4BBCC7F\"}}"
200
#<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQUAL :COUNT 17 {10039E4303}>
#<QURI.URI.HTTP:URI-HTTPS https://html2json.com/api/v1>
#<CL+SSL::SSL-STREAM for #<FD-STREAM for "socket 172.20.10.5:34050, peer: 185.94.230.235:443" {10038A5B13}>>
```

The first result (of a brig stringfied JSON) is close to what I want.

Since the JSON output is going to be printed to end users, I need (i) to remove backslash (`\`) and (ii) indent JSON.

However, the backslashes exist due to the *escape* nature they have on quotes (to avoid premature closing of the string) and I am not sure how to handle them. I am also clueless on how to pretty print it.

How can I achieve the desired result? Is there a library to solve this specific problem? If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: If you use `PRINC`, the backslashes won't be printed.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar. What about the indentation?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library you're using, I don't know if it has any function to pretty-print JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is! But it is not quickload-able. You have to download it from github.
The most convenient way to set it up however is to use roswell (which can install you github repository maintained Common Lisp packages as well as quickload-able packages).

I wrote an article once about setting up Roswell for a Development environment of Common Lisp - see: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-set-up-common-lisp-ide-in-2021-5be70d88975b
.

If you have then installed Roswell, setting up is as straight forward as:

```
$ ros install muyinliu/jsown-utils # installs from github directly
$ ros install dexador              # installs from quicklisp repo
```

And you are ready to go!

```
(ql:quickload 'jsown-utils)
(ql:quickload 'dexador)

;; https://github.com/muyinliu/jsown-utils

(jsown:pprint-json
 (dex:post "https://html2json.com/api/v1"
           :content (dex:get "https://ambrevar.xyz")))
```

`jsown:pprint-json` is exactly the function you are searching for!

The code above outputs:

```
{
    "error": [],
    "code": [],
    "message": [],
    "data": {
        "head": {
            "title": "‎",
            "meta": [
                {
                    "charset": "utf-8"
                },
                {
                    "name": "viewport",
                    "content": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "generator",
                    "content": "Org mode"
                },
                {
                    "name": "author",
                    "content": "root"
                }
            ],
            "link": [
                {
                    "rel": "stylesheet",
                    "type": "text/css",
                    "href": "../dark.css"
                },
                {
                    "rel": "icon",
                    "type": "image/x-icon",
                    "href": "../logo.png"
                }
            ],
            "script": []
        },
        "headers": [
            {
                "tagName": "h2",
                "textContent": "Contact",
                "attributes": {
                    "id": "org4051da4"
                }
            }
        ],
        "jsonLd": [],
        "iframes": [],
        "embeds": [],
        "imgs": [],
        "links": [
            {
                "text": "mail@ambrevar.xyz",
                "href": "mailto:mail@ambrevar.xyz",
                "attr": {
                    "href": "mailto:mail@ambrevar.xyz"
                }
            },
            {
                "text": "0x9BDCF497A4BBCC7F",
                "href": "ambrevar.asc",
                "attr": {
                    "href": "ambrevar.asc"
                }
            }
        ],
        "forms": [],
        "tables": [],
        "content": "Contact
Email: mail@ambrevar.xyz
PGP: 0x9BDCF497A4BBCC7F"
    }
}
```

without Roswell, you have to follow jsown-util's github Readme instructions:

```
# In shell I would do:

cd ~/quicklisp/local-projects # enter your quicklisp/local-projects
# and then git clone it:
git clone https://github.com/muyinliu/jsown-utils.git


# Then in Common Lisp to install the package using quicklisp:

(ql:quickload 'jsown-utils)
```

Basically it means to go into your `quicklisp`'s `local-projects` folder and git clone the github repository of jsown-utils there.
Because, then it is visible for `ql:quickload` which always checks in its `local-projects` folder first, before it searches for the package in the official quicklisp repo online.

Comment: This is a real gem! Thank you very much. It would be hard to find it only using search engines :)

Comment: I suggested it to be included on the Quicklisp repository: https://github.com/quicklisp/quicklisp-projects/issues/2147

Comment: @PedroDelfino true, that it would be cool if it is quickload-able, but as I showed - if you use Roswell - the package manager for Common Lisp - it - and any github repo maintained/managed lisp package - is trivial to install directly from github. It is just a `ros install` away from your finger tips! - Since Roswell allows you to switch between different Lisp implementations and different versions within the same implementation - effortlessly, it is a must-have in the toolbox of any serious Common Lisper!